# Misspelling suggestion ("did you mean") with phrase suggest and whitespace correction with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-analyzers

I use default analyzer "english" for searching documents and it is pretty good.
But also I need "did you mean" results when search query is misspelled OR search by such misspelled prhases.

What analyzers/filters/query do I need to achieve such behaveour?

**Source text**

```
Elasticsearch is a distributed, open source search and analytics engine for all types of data,
including textual, numerical, geospatial, structured, and unstructured. Elasticsearch is built
on Apache Lucene and was first released in 2010 by Elasticsearch N.V. (now known as Elastic).
Known for its simple REST APIs, distributed nature, speed, and scalability, Elasticsearch is
the central component of the Elastic Stack, a set of open source tools for data ingestion,
enrichment, storage, analysis, and visualization. Commonly referred to as the ELK Stack 
(after Elasticsearch, Logstash, and Kibana), the Elastic Stack now includes a rich collection
of lightweight shipping agents known as Beats for sending data to Elasticsearch.
```

**Search terms**

search query => did you mean XXX?

*missed letter or something like*
Elastisearch => Elasti***c***search 
distrib***a***ted => distributed 
Apac***j***e  => Apache

*extra space*
Elastic search => Elasticsearch

*no space*
opensource => open source

*misspelled phrase*
serach engne => search engine

Comment: Nice question +1 but would be great if you can explain more about your use case, some are easy to achieve in one query and some are not, so you might have to use multiple ES queries to get expected results

Comment: Generally use case only one: provide users some ways to correct misspels, but misspelling can be quite complex as I described. It's okay to use some indexes/queries for different variants, because I can combine results after.

I've added another case to question - mistake in letter.

What I need to start: some pointer to docs/examples for this cases.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example of missed letter or something else can be achieved using the [fuzzy query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html) and second one using the custom analyzer which uses [ngram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) or [edge-ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) for examples on it, please refer to [my blog on autocomplete](https://opster.com/elasticsearch-glossary/elasticsearch-auto-complete-guide/).

**Adding fuzzy query example on your sample doc**

**Index mapping**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "type": "text"
    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index your sample docs and use below search queries**

```
{
    "query": {
        "fuzzy": {
            "title": {
                "value": "distributed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And search res**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "didyou",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.89166296,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "distribated"
                }
            }
        ]
```

And for `Elasticsearch`

```
{
    "query": {
        "fuzzy": {
            "title": {
                "value": "Elasticsearch"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And search Result**

```
  "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "didyou",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.8173577,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "Elastisearch"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: I have whole text in index and many fields, so fuzzy can show results but not suggestion of words/phrases :(

Comment: @webness please refer to this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html for elasticsearch suggestors

Comment: @webness any luck?

Comment: For phrase suggestion/spaces - no :( But I implemented workaround: split by words before passing query to Elasticsearch and then itereate array and seach each word separately.